# Toggle multiple items

Tags: jquery, toggle

I want the items to toggle like this.. but one problem. I can click all of the items, and they all show. I want the buttons to open the respective containers, but only show one at a time, instead of clicking on each one and they just all show.. Any ideas?

```
<script>
$("#infotab_one").click(function() {
    $("#infotab_one_s").slideToggle("slow", "linear");
});

$("#infotab_two").click(function () {
    $("#infotab_two_s").slideToggle("slow", "linear");
});

$("#infotab_three").click(function () {
    $("#infotab_three_s").slideToggle("slow", "linear");
});

$("#infotab_four").click(function () {
    $("#infotab_four_s").slideToggle("slow", "linear");
});

$("#infotab_five").click(function () {
    $("#infotab_five_s").slideToggle("slow", "linear");
});
```

I want an option to color the boxes labeled "infotab_one" as well as the others (not the _s) a color when the item is toggled. Thanks!

Comment: That must code repetition smells.

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Are you essentially looking for accordion-like behavior?

Answer (score 0):

```
var slideAllUp = function(){
    $("#infotab_one_s").slideUp("slow");
    $("#infotab_two_s").slideUp("slow");
    $("#infotab_three_s").slideUp("slow");
    $("#infotab_four_s").slideUp("slow");
    $("#infotab_five_s").slideUp("slow");
};

$("#infotab_one").click(function() {
    slideAllUp();
    $("#infotab_one_s").slideToggle("slow", "linear");
});

$("#infotab_two").click(function () {
    slideAllUp();
    $("#infotab_two_s").slideToggle("slow", "linear");
});

$("#infotab_three").click(function () {
    slideAllUp();
    $("#infotab_three_s").slideToggle("slow", "linear");
});

$("#infotab_four").click(function () {
    slideAllUp();
    $("#infotab_four_s").slideToggle("slow", "linear");
});

$("#infotab_five").click(function () {
    slideAllUp();
    $("#infotab_five_s").slideToggle("slow", "linear");
});
```

I dislike this solution, for the following reason:

Too much code. It is usually a good idea to try and use the least code as possible, and this can be shortened by using *classes.* That way, you can do fun stuff like:

```
$(".tab").click(function(){
    $(".desc").slideUp("slow");
    $(".desc[id='"+$(this).attr("desc_id")+"']").slideDown("slow");
});
```

Comment: I agree about the shortening, but the shortened version won't actually work, and you can write a better ID selector than that anyway.

Comment: True...but the fact still stand using classes would help.

Comment: this doesnt seem to work.. Also, if I click one of the divs (with no others showing), it ends up toggling itself, thus hiding everything. Is there a way to stop that?